# Motor not working on HP Laserjet 2300 (error 13.01.00)

Tags: printing, hp-laserjet

I have an HP Laserjet 2300 printer and it suddenly stopped printing. Whenever I try to print something, it reports the error code "13.01.00" which normally means that there is a paper jam in one of the trays. Only there is no jam.

I searched for an answer for a few hours and tried all the tips I found, including:

- removing all dirt and dust
- checking the spring mechanism in the paper tray which pushes the paper up
- checking the pickup roller
- checking the sensor flag next to the pickup roller

When checking the pickup roller I tried printing a test page with the tray out by pressing up the sensor flag and I noticed that the pickup roller is not even moving. The printer seems to be trying to move it, but stops after two attempts, each of which is accompanied by a clicking sound. It then stops and reports the error message. So it seems there is some problem with the motor or the gears.

Maybe someone has had this problem too and might be able to provide some insight.